# SendAsync will not reply all request every time

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

From code below, Sometimes, it will not reply all ping request, and will wait for infinite period of time.Is there any deadlock issue? if yes How to handle it? How can I get correct result for every ip without any deadlock?

```
class Program
    {        
        static Semaphore PingSender { get; set; }
        static object lockObj = new object();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            long pingSent = 0;
            long pingReceived = 0;
            PingSender = new Semaphore(10000, 10000);

            for (int dotNoDot = 1; dotNoDot <= 255; dotNoDot++)
            {
                for (int dotNo = 1; dotNo <= 255; dotNo++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string ipAddress = string.Format("111.222.{0}.{1}", dotNoDot, dotNo);       //Please change necessary ip base
                        PingSender.WaitOne();
                        Ping ping = new Ping();
                        ping.PingCompleted += (sender, eventArgs) =>
                        {
                            //lock (lockObj)
                            //{
                                PingSender.Release(1);
                                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}) Address: {1} and Status: {2}", pingReceived, eventArgs.UserState, eventArgs.Reply.Status));
                                if (eventArgs.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                                {
                                    //collect online machines
                                }
                                Interlocked.Increment(ref pingReceived);
                                if (pingReceived == pingSent)
                                {
                                    //done
                                }
                            //}
                        };
                        //lock (lockObj)
                        //{
                            pingSent++;
                       // }
                        ping.SendAsync(ipAddress, 10000, ipAddress);                       

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }

                }
            }           
        }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using two different locking premitives at the same time? (`Semaphore` and a `lock`)?

Comment: Yuval, I commented some code. Please check